# docker: configure logging options

Tags: docker, logging

According to the [official docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/), to configure logging options (such as max log file size), one should tweak the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file.

However, the only file in my system under `/etc/docker` is `key.json`.

How can I set / get the max file size for logging? (per container or system-wide?)

docker: `17.09.1-ce`

os: `Ubuntu 16.04.03`

on `aws` `ec2` `t2.small` instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new daemon.json file using this:

`cat << EOF > /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
    "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"],
    "tls": true,
    "tlsverify": true,
    "tlscacert": "/etc/docker/ca.pem",
    "tlscert": "/etc/docker/server-cert.pem",
    "tlskey": "/etc/docker/server-key.pem",
    "log-opts": {
        "max-size": "10m",
        "max-file": "2"
    }
}`

2. Reference it in the init script for dockerd

`mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
cat << EOF > /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/custom.conf
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 --config-file /etc/docker/daemon.json
EOF`

3. Restart your docker daemon

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker`

This assumes that you're using TLS to access dockerd remotely (strongly recommended). I suspect that you're not since your `/etc/docker` dir doesn't have any cert and keys. In that case, remove all tls entries in daemon.json and replace `tcp://0.0.0.0:2376` by `tcp://0.0.0.0:2375`.

Answer (score 1):

The `/etc/docker/daemon.json` doesn't exist by default. You can create it and configure the logging options. Make sure to restart the docker service afterwards.

```
systemctl restart docker.service
```